# How do I check if an assembly reference exists in the GAC?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, reference, gac

My EntityFramework reference has a yellow triangle warning left of it, and my project says it's missing.

> Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly
>   "EntityFramework, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to
>   make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required
>   by your code, you may get compilation errors.

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GAC path is `C:\Windows\assembly`.

However, you resolve your error, you must use NuGet to install the EntityFramework package (or do it manually but that's harder and doesn't allow you to upgrade).

1. Install [NuGet](http://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CGMQjBAwAQ&url=http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases&ei=GSe_T8q0ENLZ8QO2gKXGCg&usg=AFQjCNG2_W6S0YScmgF-kVT5cwcEUjvgmg&sig2=n5JA3fWpn0eKV9mX6N7R7w) if you haven't already
2. Right click on your project and "Manage NuGet packages"
3. Search for EntityFramework
4. Install

Later, you can use the same dialog under "Updates" to install updated versions of the EntityFramework.

In the case that you need to install 4.1.0.0 in particular because a third-party lib is using it and won't work with anything higher, install the appropriate package version from [here](https://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework).

Comment: +1, good answer. Even if you install the assembly to GAC, in the application server you will have to install it again. It is better to carry the assembly with the install package.

Comment: So that other people can edit it and add info if they find it appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Run the installer.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=8363

I had the same issue. Its fixed now. The entity framework dll was missing from the GAC, its present after running the installer.

(You can verify the dll is missing from the GAC by opening the GAC c:\windows\assembly and seeing if it is listed.)

Comment: The link is dead.